# how to get a previous date using another previous date as referene

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to get messages from gmail inbox between a range of 10 days.

I need a method to calculate dates something like below:

```
Date toDate = new Date();//for the first time it will be a present date
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);           
Date fromDate = calendar.getTime();//This date will be 10 days before today.
```

In the next iteration, I want messages from the "fromDate" to 10 days before "fromDate".
Now,

```
toDate = fromDate ; //and 
fromDate = fromDate-10;
```

Please tell me how to achieve this.
I am able to get the things write for the first iteration.I am stuck for the rest iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then  `from the "fromDate" to 10 days before "fromDate"` means `20` days before today.

> ```
>     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
>     System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
>     calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -10); // 10 days before today
>     Date toDate = calendar.getTime();
>       // remember now your calendar instance 10 days older than today
>       // so reduce 10 more days equals to 20 days before today
>     calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,-10); // another 10 days before today
>     Date fromDate=calendar.getTime();
>     System.out.println("from date: "+fromDate);
>     System.out.println("to date: "+toDate);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTime(Date d)` from the `Calendar` class in order to initialise it to any date you want. Then if you have previously set a date in the past, you can apply another offset

```
   Date toDate = new Date();
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);
   Date fromDate = cal.getTime(): // 10 days back from now
```

Later, either re-use `Calendar` instance if available, or create a new one initialised with the `fromDate`. Following example suppose you only have the `fromDate` :

```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(from); // which is 10 days back
   cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);
   Date fromFromDate = cal.getTime(): // now 20 days back
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the utility method which returns the past date.

For example if you wants to get date for before 20 days then pass 20 as input in this method. It will return you the date before 20 days

```
public static Date getPastDate(int dayCount) 
{
    try 
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        int daysToSubstract = dayCount * (-1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, daysToSubstract);
        Date dateBefore30Days = cal.getTime();
        return dateBefore30Days;

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
    }
}
```

**Input :** 20

**Output :** Tue Feb 10 17:58:30 IST 2015

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should look like in a loop.

```
    int numberOfIterations = 3;

    Date toDate = new Date();
    Date fromDate = null;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);
        fromDate = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(fromDate + " - " + toDate);
        toDate = fromDate;
    }
```